# POST http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make my app connecting to pusher on a private channel.

But I am getting the following error in console:

> POST http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)

app.js

```
 /**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('payment', require('./components/Payment.vue'));
Vue.component('form-ajax', require('./components/FormAjax.vue'));
Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

    Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

Echo.private(`articles.admin`)
    .listen('ArticleEvent', function(e)  {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JXI4.png)

What maybe the cause of the error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 8):

Error 403 /broadcasting/auth with Laravel version > 5.3 & Pusher, you need change your code in **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js** with

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your key',
    cluster: 'your cluster',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + YourTokenLogin
        },
    },
});
```

And in **app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php** change by

```
Broadcast::routes()
```

with

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

or

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]); //if you use JWT
```

it worked for me, and hope it help you.

Comment: how can we  use custom auth BroadcastServiceProvider.php @Alex

Comment: @Alex whats "YourTokenLogin" and how do i impliment that there?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to customise your authEndpoint.

this thing works on my end.

bootsrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    // ...
    authEndpoint: '/custom/endpoint/auth'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have used a custom auth guard which is causing the problem.

I have added the middleware to pass my custom auth guard and this solves the problem.

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:admin']);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

[This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16151) link explains more what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I added below code to `routes/web.php` and it worked.

```
 Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function () {
    return Auth::user();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have faced same problem and this trick save my life.

go to **api.php**

```
Broadcast::routes(['predix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have more than one guards. If yes, you need to specify your guard auth middleware in `Broadcast::routes()` in `BroadcastServiceProvider` like this:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web','auth:admin']]);
```

For more info: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16151

Answer (score -1):

i solved mine by double checking **typo** in the channel name